# Views misplaced when setting frames

Tags: swift, xcode

I am trying to make a view programatically, making a card with an image and some text and overlaying it with some color. I have turned off clip to bounds and added some colors to make it more visual.
So when I set

```
overlay.frame = self.frame
```

or

```
overlay.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: frame.height)
```

the overlay should cover the entire view but it does not, why is this?

[This is what is showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3J35x.jpg)

[This is what I want to see, but with each card having a blue layer on top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DY7gi.jpg)

```
private var leftImage: UIImageView = {
  let i = UIImageView(frame: .zero)
  i.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
  i.image = UIImage()
  return i
}()

private var topLabel: UILabel = {
  let label = UILabel(frame: .zero)
  label.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
  label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16.0)
  label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
  label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
  label.numberOfLines = 2
  return label
}()

var bottomLabel: UILabel = {
  let label = UILabel(frame: .zero)
  label.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
  label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
  label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12.0)
  label.numberOfLines = 1
  label.text = "60 seconds"
 return label
}()

private var stackView: UIStackView = {
  let stack = UIStackView(frame: .zero)
  stack.axis = .vertical
  stack.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
  stack.distribution = .fillEqually
  stack.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 5, right: 5)
  stack.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
  return stack
}()

private var overlay: UIView = {
  let view = UIView(frame: .zero)
  view.backgroundColor = .blue
  view.alpha = 0.8
  //view.isHidden = true
  return view
}()



override init(frame: CGRect) {
  super.init(frame: frame)
  create()
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
  super.init(coder: coder)
  create()
}




private func create() {
  self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

  //leftview
  leftImage.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width / 2, height: frame.height)
  addSubview(leftImage)

  //rightVIew
  stackView.frame = CGRect(x: frame.midX, y: 0, width: frame.width / 2, height: frame.height)

  clipsToBounds = false



  //add views to stack
  stackView.addArrangedSubview(topLabel)
  stackView.addArrangedSubview(bottomLabel)


  addSubview(stackView)

  overlay.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: frame.height)
  addSubview(overlay)

  //card styling
  layer.cornerRadius = 10
}
```

Comment: No layout constraints set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> overlay.frame = self.frame
> ```

That can never be right, except by accident, because the `frame` of `overlay` and the `frame` of `self` are in two different coordinate systems. At the very least you want to say

```
overlay.frame = self.bounds // bounds, not frame
```

However, that isn't going to work either unless you say it in the right place. The right place is when layout occurs:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.overlay.frame = self.bounds
}
```

Simply adding that to your existing code should solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you, I thought it was something with the bound/frame, but did not understand it until now!

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that you're setting your overlay's dimensions like so:

```
overlay.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: frame.height)
```

before the superview has determined its final width and height. You'll need to do one of the following:

1. Call `create()` after the superview class has determined its final size
2. Continuously set the overlay's frame as the superview's width and height changes (see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622482-layoutsubviews)
3. Use AutoLayout constraints via a xib/storyboard file